# How to set time based process builder

Tags: process-builder

Currently I am working on a process builder. My scenario is every day 1pm collection notification message need to send to case contact mobile number.I am using Twilio Message.

Any ideas to use the process builder to  trigger the messaging event?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you want time-dependent action in process builder?

Comment: Yes. I want time dependent action.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what Time-Dependent Actions do in Process Builder. They go off exactly once, a set duration after the value of some date or date-time value on a record. They don't execute on a repeating schedule.

You have a few options to pursue.

1. Scheduled Apex. This is generally the expected idiom for scheduled tasks.
2. The open source [Mass Action Scheduler](https://douglascayers-org.github.io/sfdx-mass-action-scheduler/) application by Doug Ayers, which allows scheduling Process Builder actions.
3. A more elaborate declarative process that "resets" a timer field on the record every time it runs for the next day at 1 pm. Because Process Builder Scheduled Actions can only be executed on record create or "when specified changes are made" (that is, when a criterion changes from false to true), this is difficult to achieve with Process Builder alone. However, you can pair with a Workflow Rule that's scheduled for, say, 2 hours after the timer field and sets its value to the next day at 1 pm.

I don't love (3). It feels flimsy to me, and it subjects you to the surprisingly low limits for scheduled actions (did you know you only get 1,000 per hour? It's easy to build up a long queue if you're processing a lot of records). I'd recommend using Apex, potentially Scheduled Batch Apex, to get this done.